# What are the possible sets of unit vectors $v_i\in\mathbb R^2$ summing to zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $N\ge2$ be some integer, and consider a collection of $N$ phases $\{\varphi_j\}_{j=1}^n\subset[0,2\pi]$. Is there a way to characterise the set of possible such collections summing to zero? That is, the set of collections $\{\varphi_j\}_{j=1}^N$ such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^N e^{i\varphi_j} = 0.$$
This is equivalent to asking for a characterisation for the sets of points $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^N\subset S^1\subset\mathbb R^2$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^N v_j=0$.

- For $N=2$, the solution is easy: any pair of points sitting on the same line will do.
- For $N=3$, I think the possible solutions, modulo rotations, the following:

  [image]

  We can see this because we can start from an arbitrary point, say the upper one in the above figure, and then the other two point must be placed symmetrically left and right of the first one, and to get a vanishing sum of the vertical components the angles are then bound to be $-\pi/6$ and $\pi+\pi/6$.
- For $N=4$, the solutions seem to obtained taking two arbitrary pairs of collinear points.
  I think these are exhaustive because we can always rotate the system so that the first two (or any two) are placed symmetrically with respect to the $y$ axis, and then the remaining two points are bound to respect the same symmetry and obtained reflecting the first two points with respect to the $x$ axis.
- For $N=5$, I place the first point of the $y$ axis, say at $(0,-1)$, and place the remaining $4$ points symmetrically on left and right sectors. I can then focus on the two points placed in the right sector. I can put the first point at any angle $\alpha>-\pi/6$, and then the remaining point must be at an angle $\beta$ such that
  $$2\sin\alpha-1+2\sin\beta=0\Longleftrightarrow \beta=\arcsin\left(\frac12-\sin\alpha\right).$$
  Here is a visualisation of the corresponding sets of solutions:

  [image]

  There is however another class of solutions: when three points are placed according to the $N=3$ symmetry, the remaining two can be taken as collinear on any line. This solution kind of amounts to using the $N=3$ and $N=2$ solutions independently.

More generally, for any even $N$ there is the class of solutions with $N/2$ pairs of collinear points. A direct generalisation of this is to observe that we can take any integer partition $N=n_1+...+n_\ell$, and take independently arbitrary patterns for each of the factors $n_i$, as these will all independently sum to zero.

Moreover, for any $N$ there is a "regular solution" with the points placed along regular $N$-sided polygons.

Is there a more general way to list/characterise/classify such sets of solutions for general $N$?

Comment: For five points, a set of three and a set of two can have different lines of symmetry.

Comment: @Empy2 ah, good point, I'll edit

Comment: For $N$ points, pick any $N-2$ so long as their sum is within the circle of radius two, then calculate the final two to return to zero.

Comment: @YvesDaoust wouldn't that imply that there is a single solution for $N=2$, which doesn't seem to be the case? Also, do you mean writing the equations in coordinates as $\sum_i x_i=\sum_i y_i=0$? But then you also have the constraints $x_i^2+y_i^2=1$ no?

Comment: (+1) As you note, if we take an arbitrary partition of $N = \sum_{i} N_{i}$ whose summands are all at least $2$, we can form "zero-sum" configurations of size $N_{i}$ (e.g., the regular one) and place them at arbitrary relative phases. The bottom line is, a characterization--even a recursive characterization--looks difficult. Your example with five points shows that these "partition" examples are not everything.